# Javascript changing Image every few seconds work but disables some other code

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have made a JavaScript of a changing image but it disables some other codes. You will understand what i am telling you after you see the code i wrote below. Take a gander and see whats wrong. Any help of any sorts is appreciated :D

Here is the code

HTML

```
<div class="Wrapper2">
  <div id="HomeRooms"/> </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#HomeRooms {
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(Images/Home/HomeRoomImage.jpg);
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.Wrapper2 {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

I don't know that much JavaScript and i am just a beginner. So i don't know what i just did.
Here is the JavaScript

```
var picCount=0;  
var picArray= ["Images/Home/HomeRoomImage.jpg","Images/Home/HomeRoomImage2.jpg"]
 function nextPic()
  {  picCount=(picCount+1<picArray.length)? picCount+1 : 0;
     var build='<img border="0" src="'+picArray[picCount]+
     '" position:absolute;top:100%;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;background-size:cover;background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-image: url(Images/Home/HomeRoomImage.jpg);margin:0px;padding:0px;" >\n';
     document.getElementById("HomeRooms").innerHTML=build;
     setTimeout('nextPic()',2000)
  }
```

Comment: What other code does it disable? This is probably not your issue but your HomeRooms div you have a selfclosing on. The styling you add for you image in the css, is that temp? Hou already have it in css

Comment: it disables the wrapper2 code

Comment: could you make a fiddle?

Comment: BTW, that's not how you call the setTimeout function... this is the correct way: `setTimeout(function() { nextPic(); }, 2000);`

Comment: yes. wait herehttp://jsfiddle.net/7wez07qn/

Comment: But for some reason the pictures are even changing anymore. JavaScript is frustrating

Comment: thanks IndieRok. But that still doesnt solve the problem

Comment: the fiddle doesnt illustrate my problem. I couldnt get the pictures to change. Once they change, the wrapper 2 doesnt work and it is all scaled and stuff

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you didn't specify for the code to execute on page load/document ready. Second of all, in jsfiddle, you forgot to import jquery. Also you forgot to call the initial function. You also forgot the style attribute in the img tag.

[JSFIDDLE UPDATE](http://jsfiddle.net/7wez07qn/3/)

EDIT: Now with image being responsive. P.S make sure your images all have the same width, althought I know that for the example you used two dummy images.

Html:

```
<div class="Wrapper2">
  <div id="HomeRooms"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#HomeRooms {
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#HomeRooms img{
    max-width:100%;
}

.Wrapper2 {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

I corrected the code. Here's the new version:

```
//Document ready
$(function(){
    var picCount=0;  
    var picArray= ["http://bit.ly/1uxYSSb","http://bit.ly/1oOrsO6"];

    //Initial call to execute the function
    nextPic();

    function nextPic()
    {  
        picCount=(picCount+1<picArray.length)? picCount+1 : 0;
        var build='<img border="0" src="'+picArray[picCount]+'" />';
        document.getElementById("HomeRooms").innerHTML=build;
        setTimeout(function(){nextPic();},2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: that is good, but the problem is that is does not scale down proportionately and is all messed up. That is what i have been trying to make. For responsive reasons

Comment: I will be back in about 2 hours. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: that is still not what i meant. It should have 100% width and height while also scaling responsively, like in my css code before in the original question      #HomeRooms {
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(Images/Home/HomeRoomImage.jpg);
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.Wrapper2 {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

Comment: This is hard to explain and so join me here http://jsfiddle.net/7wez07qn/3/#&togetherjs=TlopaRQOy7
so that i can work with you to explain it

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/7wez07qn/3/#&togetherjs=TlopaRQOy7

Collaboration. I cant explain explain it so see me here to help me. I am going now.

This is the current code.

```
<div class="Wrapper2">
  <div id="HomeRooms"> </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){

var picCount=0;  
var picArray= ["http://bit.ly/1uxYSSb","http://bit.ly/1oOrsO6"];

    nextPic();

 function nextPic()
  {  picCount=(picCount+1<picArray.length)? picCount+1 : 0;
     var build='<img border="0" src="'+picArray[picCount]+
     '" style="" />';
     document.getElementById("HomeRooms").innerHTML=build;
   setTimeout(function(){nextPic();},6000);
  }
});
```

CSS

```
#HomeRooms {
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#HomeRooms img{
    max-width:100%;
}

.Wrapper2 {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle. [NEW VERSION](http://jsfiddle.net/IndieRok/7wez07qn/6/). Tell me if this makes sense. To be honest, I don't think you can do better than this because if you try to always scale different images with varying ratios to fit a fixed container, you're going to have a bad time. Meaning, they will distort and scale badly. The new version I updated will show the image with black borders if it does not have a matching 16:9 dimension, but resulting in said image to always stay centered in the middle of the container.

Comment: The source of the updated code can be found here: [SOURCE](http://www.sitepoint.com/maintain-image-aspect-ratios-responsive-web-design/). Give credit where credit is due.